# Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only after 71 iterations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, valueerror

I've checked posts and haven't found a solution to my problem.  I'm getting the error I put in the subject after the code works fine.

I'm simply trying to add a row to a holder dataframe that only appends rows that aren't similar to previously appended rows.  You'll see that friend is checked against 'Target' and Target against 'Friend' in the query.

It iterates 71 times before giving me the error.  'cur' is the iterator, which is not included in this section of code.  Here's the code:

```
same = df[(df['Source']==cur) & (df['StratDiff']==0)]
holder = pd.DataFrame(index=['pbp'],columns=['Source', 'Target', 'Friend', 'SS', 'TS', 'FS'])
holder.iloc[0:0]
i=1
for index, row in same.iterrows():
    Target = row['Target']
    stratcur = row['SourceStrategy'] 
    strattar = row['TargetStrategy']
    sametarget = df[(df['Source']==Target)]
    samejoin = pd.merge(same, sametarget,  how='inner', left_on=['Target'], 
                        right_on = ['Target'])
    for index, row in samejoin.iterrows():
        Friend = row['Target']
        stratfriend = row['TargetStrategy_x']
        #print(cur, Friend, Target)
        temp = holder[holder[(holder['Source']==cur) & 
                             (holder['Target']==Friend) & (holder['Friend']==Target)]]
        if temp.isnull().values.any():
            holder.loc[i] = [cur,Target,Friend,stratcur,strattar,stratfriend]
            print(i, cur)
            i=i+1
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? If you provide a bit of example data and expected output, there might be a much shorter and faster solution, possibly involving `drop_duplicates`.

Comment: hanks for responding! I'm counting triads in a network and wanted to program it myself. Basically, cur is the unique id for each node. Friend & Target are the two other elements. If we get to the 3rd loop, they all have 'friendship' in common. If just enumerate through the network, I end up with:

cur  T  Fr
1    2  3
1    3  2
2    3  1
2    1  3
3    2  1
3    1  2
I want to only count those two once for each cur. I wanted to see if I could get python to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to update everyone.  I was able to solve this.  It took awhile, but the problem was located in line where I query holder.  It was too complex.  I simplified it into multiple, simpler queries.  It works fine now.